# "Hide if empty" does not work in Views if 'Show prefix and suffix' is enabled

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a price field that I need to hide if the value is 0. As I want to use :- as a suffix I turn on "Show prefix and suffix". Unfortunately this makes the field visible again. In my different views I have managed to hide the field anyway with this snippet in `hook_views_pre_render(&$view)`:

```
foreach($view->result as $val){
    if(isset($val->field_field_pris[0]['raw']['value'])){
        if($val->field_field_pris[0]['raw']['value'] == '0'){
            $val->field_field_pris[0]['rendered']['#access'] = FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

But in my search result page (I use the Search API module), this does not work. For some reason I have no access to the fields in the variable `$view->result`. So how can I hide a field in the search result view if the field value is zero, and still use the prefix & suffix?

EDITED: Ok, so I created a field template file as suggested and replaced the `<?php print $output ?>` line with this code:

```
<?php
if($output) {
  $pris = $row->_field_data['field_pris_tillbehor']['entity']->field_pris_tillbehor['und'][0]['value'];
  dsm($pris);
  if($pris == 0){
    dsm($row);
    hide($row->_field_data['field_pris_tillbehor']['entity']->field_pris_tillbehor);
    print $output;
  }
}?>
```

... but even though the zero value is confirmed by the dsm statement, the value still appears in the search page view.

Comment: Have you tried hiding it using the views UI?

Comment: Oh I see, yeah checking `Count the number 0 as empty` in No Results Behavior, does not work. Try creating a fields template file for your view, then do the if statement there.

Comment: That sounds as a solution, but I didn't succeed doing it in a way that works. Can you see what I am doing wrong in my edited question above?

Comment: Finally got it. Se my final edit above.

Comment: There is an issue on drupal.org relating to this: https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1239522